# How to convert PHP JSON to C# object

Tags: c#, json, parsing

I have a JSON which I get from web application. I try this parse to Object using System.Web.Script.Serialization  . But I have problem with parse

```
const String jsonWeb = @"{
    ""error"" : 0,
    ""result"" : {
        ""data"" : {
            ""1722278"" : {
                ""din"" : ""741338;361490;648450;934096;180467;209928;805500;283840;901917;110193;9438;363965;700670;647965;18399;31993;714755;242839;60436;600310;"",
                ""pid"" : ""11""
            },
            ""1752279"" : {
                ""din"" : ""970510;771034;372305;286336;926373;459655;1409;140138;692017;311733;686476;368178;735954;635501;816346;821514;768444;510380;959990;916515;"",
                ""pid"" : ""11""
            },
            ""1752280"" : {
                ""din"" : ""992662;474351;139725;998728;475954;706331;798728;744204;999194;22546;177003;4098;448658;842154;431042;970297;989184;362126;7720;720781;"",
                ""pid"" : ""11""
            }
        },
        ""pid"" : {
            ""11"" : {
                ""codejs"" : ""  very \""long\"" String      "",
                ""max"" : ""3""
            }
        },
        ""sys"" : {
            ""11"" : {
                ""1"" : {
                    ""b"" : ""Firefox"",
                    ""s"" : ""Windows""
                },
                ""2"" : {
                    ""b"" : ""Chrome"",
                    ""s"" : ""Windows""
                }
            }
        },
        ""maxgetlimit"" : 10001,
        ""setProxy"" : [],
        ""cidget"" : {
            ""111102"" : 1
        },
        ""openBrowser"" : 1
    }}";
```

I try parse this using this code but i get error. I try use this:

```
public class Pack
{
    public string din { get; set; }
    public string pid { get; set; }
}

public class MySybObject
{
    public Pack attributes { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public Result() { data = new List<MySybObject>(); }
    public List<MySybObject> data { get; set; }
}

public class Code
{
    public String codejs { get; set; }
    public String max { get; set; }
}

public class MySubPid
{
    public Code code { get; set; }
}

public class SystemReq
{
    public String b { get; set; }
    public String s { get; set; }
}

public class Sys 
{
    public SystemReq sysreq { get; set; }
}

public class Cidget
{
    public String cidget { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public Response() {}
    public string error { get; set; }
    public Result results { get; set; }
    public MySubPid pid { get; set; }
    public Sys sys { get; set; }
    public Int32 maxgetlimit { get; set; }
    public String setProxy { get; set; }
    public Cidget cidget { get; set; }
    public String openBrowser { get; set; }
}

JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Response foo = ser.Deserialize<Response>(jsonWeb);
```

But I get Error and I probably lost a number of object in data - this is important data for me.

Comment: I get only null object. 
Object Response, results is null etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there are numbers used as `keys` in your json string, it would be better to use dynamic objects in this case instead of deserializing to a class (I used [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) for this)

```
dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonWeb);
Console.WriteLine(jsonObj.result.data["1722278"].pid);
Console.WriteLine(jsonObj.result.sys["11"]["1"].b);
```

BTW: this line is wrong

```
""codejs"" : ""  very ""long"" String      ""
```

It should be something like this

```
""codejs"" : ""  very \""long\"" String      "",
```

**--EDIT--**

```
foreach (var child in jsonObj.result.data.Children())
{
    Console.WriteLine(child.Name + "=> " + child.Value.din);
}
```

Comment: wow great but I have a one question.
Console.WriteLine(jsonObj.result.data["1722278"].pid);

but I don't know number of data - this number are uses as key but value is random. Can I get information which key is available ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a try of [JSON class generator](http://jsonclassgenerator.codeplex.com/) to generate your classes, then try it again.

Update:
I had to change the JSON string in order to generate it;

```
{
    "error" : 0,
    "result" : {
        "data" : {
            "1722278" : {
                "din" : "741338;361490;648450;934096;180467;209928;805500;283840;901917;110193;9438;363965;700670;647965;18399;31993;714755;242839;60436;600310;",
                "pid" : "11"
            },
            "1752279" : {
                "din" : "970510;771034;372305;286336;926373;459655;1409;140138;692017;311733;686476;368178;735954;635501;816346;821514;768444;510380;959990;916515;",
                "pid" : "11"
            },
            "1752280" : {
                "din" : "992662;474351;139725;998728;475954;706331;798728;744204;999194;22546;177003;4098;448658;842154;431042;970297;989184;362126;7720;720781;",
                "pid" : "11"
            }
        },
        "pid" : {
            "11" : {
                "codejs" : "very long String      ",
                "max" : "3"
            }
        },
        "sys" : {
            "11" : {
                "1" : {
                    "b" : "Firefox",
                    "s" : "Windows"
                },
                "2" : {
                    "b" : "Chrome",
                    "s" : "Windows"
                }
            }
        },
        "maxgetlimit" : 10001,
        "setProxy" : [],
        "cidget" : {
            "111102" : 1
        },
        "openBrowser" : 1
    }}
```

Comment: But this generate 1722278 from data as class. This is bad for me.